# Spring MVC and request parameters binding

Tags: spring-mvc

Let us say that I have an URL of this format action.htm?key0=value0&key1=value1. I have bound this to a controller. Now, using @PathVariable how do I bind key0 and key1? For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action", params="myParam=myValue")
public String action(@PathVariable String key0, @PathVariable String key1, Model model) {
```

Does not work. All the examples that I could see were for rest style bindings, could not find anything for the key value type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RequestParam annotation, eg:

```
public String create(@Valid Message message, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer size) {
```

Alot of the examples use a value="" in the RequestParam annotation, eg:

```
@RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size
```

However, it will use the param name if no value is supplied, therefore, I think this is duplication, so prefer not to use the value="" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

For restful do this this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{key0}/{key1}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String action(@PathVariable String key0, @PathVariable String key1)
```

Comment: Do you mean for urls of rest format or will this work with the example URL that I posted?

Comment: it won't work for url that you posted, using requestparam for that